# In R, does ifelse() change the class of an object to list?

Tags: r, list, class, if-statement

Using R, the ifelse() command seems to be changing the class of a model I've saved (and reloaded) to a list instead of keeping it as "glm".

Here is the code that demonstrates the issue:

```
x1 <- c( 1:10 )
x2 <- c( 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0 )
y <- c( 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1 )

dataset <- as.data.frame( cbind( y, x1, x2 ) )

m <- glm( y ~ x1 + x2, family = binomial )
saveRDS( m, "test.rds" )

model <- readRDS( "test.rds" )
class(model)
# The object "model" is of class "glm" and "lm", and clearly not "list". The predict thus works, as the next code shows:
predict( model, dataset )

# Now, I want to assign the model if a certain condition is true (which I've replaced with TRUE to simplify the question, and a different model if the condition is FALSE. The issue is that the following assignment changes the class of model from "glm" "lm" to "list":

assign <- ifelse( TRUE, model )
class(assign)

# Now the object "assign", which should be the same as model (right?), is of class "list", and the following line of code fails to work:

predict( assign, dataset )
```

The last "predict" command gives this error message:

Error in UseMethod("predict") :
no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "list"

Can someone explain why the class was changed? How can I get the predict command to work on my assign?

Comment: It is better not to use `ifelse`.  Your syntax is not correct as well as `ifelse` needs 3 arguments and all arguments should be of same length.  Here, you may need `if/else`.  In addition, model objects have complex structure and thus all the arguments in the ifelse may not have the same structure.  With if/else, it should work, i.e. `if(TRUE) yourassign <- model`

Comment: A valuable lesson. I've been wedded to ifelse() structure, and I now see reason to deviate from that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/ifelse) of the `ifelse` function, the return value of the function call `ifelse(test, yes, no)` is:

> A vector of the same length and attributes (including dimensions and `"class"`) as `test` and data values from the values of `yes` or `no`. [...]

As `TRUE` has length 1, you are getting a vector of length one back.

It seems like the functionality you desire can be achieved with:

```
if (test) {
  assign <- model
} else {
  assign <- the_other_model
}
```